# What is the dimension of the G-invariant space?

Tags: representation-theory

I have difficulty proving the following statement:
Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}G$-representation and define $V^G=\{v\in V\mid g\cdot v=v\forall g\in G\}$. We want to show $\dim V^G=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \chi_V(g)$.

Here is my idea, up to change of basis, we write the $V^G$ in the first $k$ coordinates, then we get a block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I_k & B(g)\\ 0 &C(g)\end{bmatrix}$ and clearly $tr(I_k)=k$, so now it remains to show $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} tr(C(g))=0$. Is this the right way to do? Since I don't know how to show this.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $V$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of irreducible representations. One approach would be to show that $V^G$ is the direct sum of all the irreducible components that are copies of the trivial one-dimensional representation. Once you have done this, it should then be possible to derive your result using that fact that the character of the trivial one-dimensional representation is $\chi_{\rm trivial}(g) = 1$ for all $g \in G$, as well as the fact that characters for distinct irreps are orthogonal.

Feel free to ask further questions if you would like more clarification.